# $.keynavigator() arrow down, makes page go down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code for selecting suggestions works fine. There's only one annoying thing. On arrowdown, the document goes down too, -- as it does/should in a browser. But this creates confusion, because vital parts (e.g. header) of the page are not visible any more.

I believe I mixed up some things too, the jquery `keyup` and the `keynavigator`, this could be cleaner, and maybe this is the problem for the page to go down(?).

```
$(document).keyup(function( e ) {
    if(e.which==38 || e.which==40){
            $("#suggesties").focus();
        }
});

$('#suggesties label').keynavigator({ 
    cycle: true,
    activeClass: 'alert-success',
    keys: {
        enter: function($el,e) {
            $el.click();
            $("#initials").focus();
        }
    }
});
```

**Question**:
How can I prevent the page from going down when the down arrow is fired?

**Edit**

The problem is that the cursor is first focused on a field, the field produces a list from which I want to select with the keyboard. So the first hit on the arrow down will only result in leaving the input field, and causes the page to scroll down a bit. After the second hit it selects the second result.

> I'm sorry, I thought I really covered the whole question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [prevent the default behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) for those keys.

Something like this:

```
$(document).keyup(function( e ) {
    if(e.which==38 || e.which==40){
       e.preventDefault();
       $("#suggesties").focus();
     }
});
```

Just to be safe, make sure you prevent the default behaviour for `onkeydown` events as well (for those two keys), because the keydown event usually triggers the browser scroll:

```
$(document).keydown(function( e ) {
    if(e.which==38 || e.which==40){
       e.preventDefault();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this sample code in jsFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/5zpeho6b/2/

```
$(document).keyup(function( e ) {
    if(e.which==38 || e.which==40) {
        console.log('key '+(e.which==38?'up':'down'));
        $("ul#example1").focus();
    }
});

$('ul#example1 li').keynavigator({ 
    cycle: true,
    activeClass: 'alert-success',
    keys: {
        enter: function($el,e) {
            $el.click();
            $("#content").focus();
        }
    }
});
```

It works as it should, the page does not scroll. I cannot reproduce your situation where keydown scrolls the page when the focus is on the keynavigator element.

Can you provide more information like all the HTML, CSS and JS code?